# How to access first element easily in multidimensional array?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list like so:

```
[("How", 0.23),("Like", 1.23),("Book",0.53)]
```

All I want is to loop through the list and put the strings into a new list like this:

```
["How", "like", "Book"]
```

I know a nested loop can do it, but is there any simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Following that, either access the string as a first element of each tuple by indexing, or unpack the tuple into 2 elements:

```
my_list = [("How", 0.23),("Like", 1.23),("Book",0.53)]

# Get the first element by indexing:
my_strings = [x[0] for x in my_list]

# OR:

# Unpack the tuple:
my_strings = [s for s, n in my_list]
```